# Mail chimp send email using V 3.0

Tags: web-services, rest, mailchimp

I want to send one email using `mail chimp v 3.0 API`, but I am not sure which exact end point we need to use. I am checking [this].(http://developer.mailchimp.com/documentation/mailchimp/reference/overview/)

But still not exactly sure which end point can send the email.

Answer (score 0):

Campaign Creation and Sending are [not yet in MailChimp API v3.0](http://developer.mailchimp.com/documentation/mailchimp/guides/get-started-with-mailchimp-api-3/#roadmap).